# Anomalous Google Directive turning on all devices, what may have caused this?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

We have been developing a Google Home action over the past weeks. Just today, an internal tester turned off a *Room* with a few lights, in preparation to leave the house. Roughly 15 seconds later, we see in our logs, a directive came in to seemingly turn on every device that supported the OnOff trait. This has not been double checked at this time. Suffice it to say, though, *a lot* of things were turned on.

See below our server logs of the original turning off of a room, followed by the unexpected and undirected command:

```
__INPUT_________________________________________________________
[ UTC 14:40:16 12/1/2018 ] 
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE",
      "payload": {
        "commands": [
          {
            "devices": [
              {
                 "customData": {
                  "colorTemperatureRange": null,
                  "dimLevelRange": {
                    "max": 15,
                    "min": 0
                  },
                  "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
                },
                "id": "26782020"
              },
              {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "24175054"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": null,
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "23742906"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "27706708"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "26164657"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": null,
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "26597087"
          }
        ],
        "execution": [
          {
            "command": "action.devices.commands.OnOff",
            "params": {
              "on": false
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
  ],
  "requestId": "3392868800863712071"
}

__RESPONSE______________________________________________________
[ UTC 14:40:16 12/1/2018 ] {
  "requestId": "3392868800863712071",
  "payload": {
"commands": [
  {
    "states": {
      "on": false,
      "online": true
    },
    "ids": [
      "26782020",
      "24175054",
      "23742906",
      "27706708",
      "26164657",
      "26597087"
    ],
    "status": "SUCCESS"
  }
]
  }
}

__INPUT_________________________________________________________
[ UTC 14:40:30 12/1/2018 ] {
  "inputs": [
{
  "intent": "action.devices.EXECUTE",
  "payload": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "devices": [
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 15,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "26782020"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": null,
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "18951651"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "20134799"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": null,
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "28426103"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "24175054"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "31877951"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "31880526"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": null,
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "23742906"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "23190599"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "27706708"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "31750691"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "18848065"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "19152838"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "19530298"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "25920089"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": null,
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "29823155"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 15,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "23647259"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "26164657"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "20730915"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "27374037"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "33430648"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 15,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "24978508"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": null,
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "26597087"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": {
                "max": 600,
                "min": 0
              },
              "dimLevelRange": {
                "max": 255,
                "min": 0
              },
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "32442642"
          },
          {
            "customData": {
              "colorTemperatureRange": null,
              "dimLevelRange": null,
              "onOffMode": "/on_off/"
            },
            "id": "32558185"
          }
        ],
        "execution": [
          {
            "command": "action.devices.commands.OnOff",
            "params": {
              "on": true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
  ],
  "requestId": "11563706689114380169"
}

__RESPONSE______________________________________________________
[ UTC 14:40:31 12/1/2018 ] {
  "requestId": "11563706689114380169",
  "payload": {
"commands": [
  {
    "states": {
      "on": true,
      "online": true
    },
    "ids": [
      "26782020",
      "18951651",
      "20134799",
      "28426103",
      "24175054",
      "31877951",
      "31880526",
      "23742906",
      "23190599",
      "27706708",
      "31750691",
      "18848065",
      "19152838",
      "19530298",
      "25920089",
      "29823155",
      "23647259",
      "26164657",
      "20730915",
      "27374037",
      "33430648",
      "24978508",
      "26597087",
      "32442642",
      "32558185"
    ],
    "status": "SUCCESS"
  }
]
  }
}
```

(Apologies if the JSON formatting is a bit off)

The user claims not to have spoken any directives after turning off the one room. Beyond determining in the logs that an out-of-the-ordinary directive did get processed by our server, we have no idea what may caused this.

Has anyone else experienced a directive out of nowhere like this?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Are all your testers using the same account on your end? Is something happening with your OAuth server which is allowing other user's devices to be controlled?

Comment: All our testers have their own account. We cannot rule out with absolute certainty that there is a fault in our OAuth security, allowing a 3rd party to control another user's devices, but this seems unlikely - especially considering the small scale that we are currently testing at. Clearly, this is an odd occurrence, and we have only seen it this one time. Unless others have experienced the same thing, or it is a known bug, it is difficult to say at this time what might have caused it.